# Serializing POCO Excluding Class Members

Tags: c#, serialization, poco, class-hierarchy

I wish to make a POCO [Serializable] but not any other class members in its class hierarchy tree. I know there is [NonSerialized] which works only for fields, but is there any way to exclude them or choose specific members using [Serializable] on the POCO?

Answer (score 4):

You should look at the [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx); it uses an "opt-in" approach to serialization.

Also it would be a good idea to read [XmlSerializer vs DataContractSerializer: Serialization in Wcf](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/) to for examples and a comparison between `DataContractSerializer` and `XmlSerializer`.

> The XmlSerializer has been in .Net
>   since version 1.0 and has served us
>   well for everything from Remoting, Web
>   Services, serializing to a file, etc.
>   However in .Net 3.0 the
>   DataContractSerializer came along. 
>   And all of a sudden a lot of guidance
>   suggests that we should use it over
>   the old tried and true XmlSerializer.
>   Wcf even uses this as the default
>   mechanism for serialization.  The
>   question is, “Is it really better?”. 
>   The verdict is yes, and no.  Like most
>   things it depends on your
>   implementation and what you need.  For
>   Wcf, you should prefer to use the
>   DataContractSerializer.  If you need
>   full control over how the xml looks
>   though, you should go back to the
>   XmlSerializer.

Comment: Good answer (I've deleted mine) - just to add (for the OP): if you want tight binary serialization, you might consider protobuf-net.

Comment: @Marc - protobuf-net is a good choice as well and well worth its own answer.  If you undelete your answer I will upvote it.